# Clear EditText error message onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop

In my **Android 5.0** project, I have an `EditText` widget which displays errors with `setError(error)` method. If I try to clear error with `setError(null)` in `onActivityResult` callback, the error persists: the view is not updated but I am sure the `setError(null)` is invoked. I tried an `invalidate()` statement after but doesn't solve the problem. It is a bug of Android 5.0 Lollipop or there is a new practice to clear an error message?

The problem is present in Android 5.0 (API 21) Emulator but not in 4.1.1 (API 16)

---

**Edit**: A Project Member answered:

`This has been fixed internally but is not in AOSP yet.`

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81870

Comment: setError(null) should remove an error message and an icon as declared in Android documentation. Are you sure, you do not call this function twice some how?

Comment: I realised many tests to be 100% sure. The 'getError()' result is `NULL` but the view is not updated and the icon and text error are always visible. (Only on Android 5.0)